# Find the change of basis matrix P from S to S'.

Tags: matrices

Consider the following bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
-2 
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\
-4 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

$$S'=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
3
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\
8 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Find the change of basis matrix P from S to S'.

So I followed a guide online which said to express S in terms of S':

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
-2 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}a+\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\
8 
\end{pmatrix}b$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
3\\
-4 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}c+\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\
8 
\end{pmatrix}d$$

So I got $a=-14,b=5,c=-36,d=13$ so would the answer simply be:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
-14 & 5\\
-36 & 13
\end{pmatrix}$$

or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

With your notation, I think your final matrix should be 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&c\\b&d \end{pmatrix}$$